# combine two bitmap and save as one image

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to combine two bitmaps and set it into imageview and also save that bitmap when i click button,but when i combine bitmap set it into image at that time it shows second bitmap bigger than it's real size.here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getBitmap(image1);
        Bitmap drawingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(parts.getWidth(),
                            parts.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(drawingBitmap);

        canvas.drawBitmap(parts,0,0,null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(touch,0,0,null);

        bit=drawingBitmap;

        public void getBitmap(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
            v.draw(c);

        touch=bitmap;
    }

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SaveImage save = new SaveImage();
            save.Save(getApplicationContext(),bit);
        }
    });

}
```

here **parts** is bitmap for hold camera picture and **image1** is dynamically created imageview.

SaveImage.java

```
package com.example.tattoodesign;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SaveImage {

    private Context TheThis;
    private String NameOfFolder = "/PaintImage";
    public String NameOfFile = null;
    //private ArrayList<Bitmap> images = null;

     public void Save(Context context,Bitmap ImageToSave){
            TheThis = context;
            String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ NameOfFolder;
            String CurrentDateAndTime= getCurrentDateAndTime();
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            NameOfFile="PaintImage"+CurrentDateAndTime+ ".jpg";

            if(!dir.exists()){
               dir.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(dir,NameOfFile);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file);

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                UnableToSave();}
            catch (IOException e){
                UnableToSave();
            }

        }

    private void MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(File file) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(TheThis,
                new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });

    }

    private String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        return formattedDate;
    }

    private void UnableToSave() {
        Toast.makeText(TheThis, "Picture cannot to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
  }
```

how can i fix this problem?

any help would be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that the image is being shown "bigger than it's real size".
It's more likely that it's "real size" is just not what you think it is.

Remember that the apparent size is related to both pixel width/height and dpi.

I think that you should look into scaling one of the images to match the other.
See, for example, [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

Comment: This might be the case.Adding to this answer, May be try combining the same image, just to see if its fine or still the 2nd image is bigger than the first.

Comment: When i try to combine same image than it is fine,but when i try to combine different image then 2nd image is bigger than the first.